# Mail server configuration MX Record

Tags: email-server, mx-record

i want to setup a mail server. I added MX record to NS server and now i would like to know which port i should open, maybe just smtp 25?
In this case can I set SMTP to use SSL connection (with an auto-verified certificate) and user/password authentication or should I leave a unsafe connection?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you created an MX record then I assume this server is for receiving mail that is addressed to your users and arriving from other servers on the Internet.

For this usage:

- use port 25
- do not require AUTH
- reject all recipients that are not valid users of your server (don't be an open relay)
- you might be able to require STARTTLS, though it might possibly prevent certain servers from sending to you

The situation is different if you have users that will send mail out through this server.  In this case the MX record is not used.  For this use:

- require STARTTLS
- require AUTH, but only after STARTTLS
- require the MAIL FROM (envelope sender) to match the authenticated user

Comment: Where can i find the "reject all recipients that are not valid users of your server" option in exchange, please? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know.  I use [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/).